# Kendo Grid Update posts all records to the ASP.net Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Grid to do CRUD operations. the kendo model and columns are generated dynamically from an SQL table. My problem now is when i update a row, its sending the entire rows as a post. what will be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be because of primary key(`ID`) value.

> You should return the primary key values to kendo grid on save from
>   server side. Otherwise all records will be treated as new records
>   since there is no identity column.

you may define your primary key in `schema` as below:

```
schema: {
                                model: {
                                    id: "ProductID",
                                    fields: {
                                        ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                        //other fields
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

References:

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058718/kendo-ui-grid-posting-back-already-inserted-rows-again)
[Telerik forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-ui-grid-inserts-updates-create-duplicate-records)